# how to use create feature in a selector in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have refactored my ngrx code, that means that I have change reducer to Feature.
becase in Selector I can use testFeature.selectTestData this feature.

But now I have a question,

the state is defined such as

```
testDataState = {
 personGroups: Person[],
 savePerson: Person,
 deletePerson: Person,
 updatePerson: Person
}
```

so in selector, I can use

```
export const getPersonsGroups = textPersonFeature.selectPersonGroups;
```

my question is,

how can I get only one personGroup using groupId in selector?

before changing to createFeature, I can use

```
export const getSelectedPersonGroup = createSelector(getTestDataState, (state: TestDataModuleState) => {
  const personGroups: Person[] = [...state.PersonGroup];
  if (state.groupId) {
    return personGroups.find((person: Person) => Person.id === state.groupId);
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

but after chaning I can not use this.

any solution?